# How do you make the colour of a h1 tag to change if the user hovers over the body in css and html?

Tags: html, css

I was trying this (code below) but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Can you not embed in css?

```
 html {
        transition: background;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }

    html:hover {
        background : #ffb7b7;
        h1 {
          color : blue;
        }       
    }
```

I want it so that when the user hovers over the html page, it should change the colour of the h1 tag to blue. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: See how to do it here: http://jsfiddle.net/57v5s8kp/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you cannot embed descendant rules, that requires [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or another [CSS preprocessor](https://csspre.com/compare/).

Instead, use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), which is just a space():

```css
html {
  transition: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

html:hover {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}

html:hover h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover over me!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this read [:hover doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```
 html {
        transition: background;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }

    html:hover h1{
        background : #ffb7b7;
        color : blue;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
h1:hover{
color: blue;}
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow as they tend to be unclear. Please consider adding a small explanation about what this rule does, as well as linking to relevant documentation.